# Не могу установить самописный модуль для prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

При попытке установить свой модуль для Prestashop получаю следующую ошибку:
`Вам нельзя отключать модуль redirectly.`
При этом данный модуль в списке установленных отсутствует, в списке неустановленных - тоже. Пытался его ставить через архив и переносом в папку с модулями - результат 0.
Вот метод установки данного модуля:

```
public function installDB(){
        $sql = new SQL();
        $sql->install();
    }
    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->installDB();
            $this->registerHook('header') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayDev')&&
            $this->registerHook('displayDev1');
    }
```

PrestaShop v 1.7.6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего такое может происходить в случаях попыток клонирования модуля и установки вместе с его старыми файлами и классами от composer. Надо пробовать устанавливать модуль без всех этих файлов и без других файлов прежнего модуля типа config.xm, config_ru.xml и т.п., которые могут включать названия, адреса или описания от оригинала.